# How aggressively am I being cheated on?

Tags: burnout-paradise

Racing games have long been celebrated<sup>[citation needed]</sup> for their unmatched ability to keep two completely different sets of rules and physics in mind: One set for the player, one set for the computer.

How big of an offender is Burnout Paradise in this respect; and what race types are the most stacked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Burnout Paradise does suffer from some [Rubber Band AI](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RubberBandAI) issues, but mostly it plays fair in the Race events.  It's possible to get into the lead and stay there if you pick a fast car, drive reasonably fast in the straightaways, and corner carefully.

During Marked Man events, however, it does not matter how fast your car is or how many of the other cars you take down.  Cars will catch up with you even though you should have a commanding lead.  The game even spawns cars going beyond top speed to catch you in if you take them all down.  I've run these with what should be the fastest car in the game and still not been able to outrun them.

Road Rage events seem to be kind of backwards - cars seem to slow up to let you catch up and take them down most of the time.  New cars that spawn (or, I suppose respawn) might overtake you, but then they kind of coast a bit so you can catch up.  It's not unusual in these events for me to get a takedown "Rampage" or similar.

Also worth noting - during a takedown animation, *your* car gets to play by the "cheating" physics rules and won't crash in some situations where a crash seemed inevitable from your perspective.

The other events don't really have opponents (except the clock) so there's not a lot of AI cheating to be had.

Comment: What about ambient traffic; does the AI wield that for its own nefarious purposes?

Comment: @WillihamTotland, not that I'm aware of.  I've not noticed any difference in the amount of traffic during races.  If anything, I think the roads tend to be pretty clear.

Comment: I'm thinking not so much about the _amount_ of ambient traffic, more the _behavior_. Occasionally I get the distinct feeling that cars swerve into me on purpose. "Speeding through an intersection, are you? TOO BAD I'M MAKING A LEFT TURN!"

Comment: @WillihamTotland, Dunno about that particular way in which the AI could cheat.

Comment: @agent86 - I believe Williham means that, for example, if you're leading, the AI will have traffic cars deliberately get in your way to sabotage you.

Comment: @Compro01, I know what he meant; I just don't know if the AI cheats in that way, or how I would test it.  I don't think I could discern cheating behavior from random behavior without a larger sample size than I can realistically capture in a timeframe reasonable for an Arqade answer, I guess is what I'm trying to say.